# Cannot add map in Android Studio as stated in Google "Getting Started" page; Android Studio gives error

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio

I'm trying to follow the directions to make an app with the Google Maps API. To do this, I'm following the instructions exactly as described [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#add_a_map): I already had Android Studio and worked on a couple of very elementary Contact List apps, but for this I got the API key, set up the location and network permissions and set up OpenGL ES v2. 
I copied the following two sections of code right from the website and pasted it to the activity .xml file and the java class.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

to the layout XML file and the following to the MainActivity.java file.

```
package com.example.mapdemo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

I run into a problem with the first block of code. Android Studio returns the "`android.gms.maps.MapFragment`" as an error, by highlighting it red. It also gives me an error for all usages of `R`... any usage of `R`is highlighted in red. I tried importing `android.R` but didn't work. But I guess one problem at a time.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Did you add google play services to your dependencies? The R issue should be fixed once the map issue is fixed.

Comment: I actually hadn't. So I just added this line to my build.gradle: "compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'". The MapFragment error disappeared. But I still have the R class error. And that's preventing me from compiling and running the app.

Comment: Have you cleaned and rebuilt since including the dependency?

Comment: Yep, didn't work. Error persists.

Comment: Are you still importing `android.R`? If so, remove that import statement.

Comment: I removed it after testing it. I still have the R class error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:  I just started a new project and followed the instructions from that link.  It worked for me.
One thing to note is that I didn't have to change anything in `MainActivity.java`.

I would recommend starting a new project in Android Studio, select "Blank Activity". 
Modify `AndroidManifest.xml`, `build.gradle`, and `activity_main.xml`, but leave everything in `MainActivity.java` as is.

One thing to note is that from the SDK Manager, you need to install:

- Android Support Repository
- Android Support Library
- Google Play Services
- Google Repository

From my working example:

In build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.0.0'
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="*********************"/>

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

</application>
```

I got it set up with a `Fragment` within `MainActivity`.

activity_main.xml (nothing special here):

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

fragment_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

MainActivity.java:

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.location.Location;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        MapView mMapView;
        private GoogleMap googleMap;
        Location location;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // inflate and return the layout
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                    false);
            mMapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
            mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            mMapView.onResume();// needed to get the map to display immediately

            try {
                MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            googleMap = mMapView.getMap();
            googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

            location = googleMap.getMyLocation();

            if (location != null) {

                // latitude and longitude
                LatLng lat = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

                //double latitude = 17.385044;
                //double longitude = 78.486671;
                //LatLng lat = new LatLng(latitude,longitude);


                // create marker

                MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(
                        lat).title("Hello Maps");

                // Changing marker icon
                marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ROSE));

                // adding marker
                googleMap.addMarker(marker);

                CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                        .target(lat).zoom(12).build();


                googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                        .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

            }

            // Perform any camera updates here
            return v;
        }


        @Override
        public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            mMapView.onResume();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            mMapView.onPause();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            mMapView.onDestroy();
        }

        @Override
        public void onLowMemory() {
            super.onLowMemory();
            mMapView.onLowMemory();
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I do have all those installed from the original download. I just checked and updated them. Cleaned and rebuilt the project again. No changes.

Comment: Thanks, I think the problem was in some repeated lines of code. I had to rearrange some import lines in the XML file. No errors anymore. Have to wait to see if the code actually does what it's supposed to, since I don't have the USB cable to test on my phone right now... Virtual Device is asking me to install Google Play Services, which I already have.