# Parse double value and set in TextView

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, android-parser

For parse data I use **retrofit (gson) library**. I have problems with parsing **double value 'position'**. The full JSON you can see here below. I parse String array 'words' great but with double value I have nothing in TextView. Can anyone say what exactly wrong and what I need to fix and what I missed?

*Thanks for any help!*

**JSON**

[image]

**MainActivity.java**

```
w3wNetworkFactory.w3wGetInstance().w3wGetApiCall().getPosition(w3w_API_KEY, new Words("gliders.inquest.hardly"), new Callback<PositionResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void success(PositionResponse positionResponse, Response response) {
                position_w3w.setText(Arrays.toString(positionResponse.getPosition()).replaceAll("\\[|\\]", ""));
                //Log.d("w3w location: ", Arrays.toString(positionResponse.getPosition()));
                String mLatLng = Arrays.toString(positionResponse.getPosition()).replaceAll("\\[|\\]", "");
                //Convert String to double
                double value = Double.parseDouble(mLatLng);
                //Set marker to map
                mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(value)
                        .title("Geolocation system")
                        .snippet("Your last current location which was available!")
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.icon_location)));
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                error.toString();
            }
        });
```

**PositionResponse.java**

```
public class PositionResponse {
    private double[] position;

    public double[] getPosition() {
        return position;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would recommend logging the values you receive in your `PositionResponse` object.  I just tested your `Arrays.toString(positionResponse.getPosition()).replaceAll("\\[|\\]", "")` statement, and it looks like it works as expected.

Comment: Hello man. You mean that statement is not correct? I dont understand your idea exactly. I also used Log Log.d("w3w location: ", Arrays.toString(positionResponse.getPosition())); instead of Arrays.toString(positionResponse.getPosition()).replaceAll("\\[|\\]", "") just to see what will be in logcat. Unfortunaltly I have nothing in logcat too. Do you know the reason?

Comment: The statement is correct. I tested it and it works.  Log the values of `double[] position` inside `PositionResponse` to make sure they are getting populated in there.

Comment: Hello man! I found my mistake. It was here return String.format("%f,%f", words); Stupid mistake. But I have one more question. As you see from JSON its latitude and longitude. I want to set marker in Google map but have red line here: .position(value) Can you check my post again. I updated it. What I did wrong again.

Comment: I think I see the issue.  Posting an answer now.

Comment: Thank you for the accept!  It would now probably be best to modify the title of your question to something like `Getting location result of w3w API into Google Map`, and add and edit to the question as well, so that future readers of the question don't get confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question about the Google Map, you need to separate out the lat and lon, and create a [LatLng object](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLng.html). I think it should be something like this:

```
    @Override
                public void success(PositionResponse positionResponse, Response response) {
                    position_w3w.setText(Arrays.toString(positionResponse.getPosition()).replaceAll("\\[|\\]", ""));
                    //Log.d("w3w location: ", Arrays.toString(positionResponse.getPosition()));
                    String mLatLng = Arrays.toString(positionResponse.getPosition()).replaceAll("\\[|\\]", "");

                    String[] arrLatLng = mLatLng.split(","); //separate out lat and lon
                    LatLng latLon = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(arrLatLng[0]), Double.parseDouble(arrLatLng[1])); //create the LatLng object

                    //Convert String to double
                    //double value = Double.parseDouble(mLatLng); this wouldn't work, you need to do both values individually
                    //Set marker to map, use LatLng object latLon
                    mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLon)
                            .title("Geolocation system")
                            .snippet("Your last current location which was available!")
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.icon_location)));

                     CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                        .target(latLon).zoom(12).build();


                     mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                        .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
                }
```

For more detailed info on getting Google Maps API fully set up, see my other answer here: [Cannot add map in Android Studio as stated in Google "Getting Started" page; Android Studio gives error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29505087/cannot-add-map-in-android-studio-as-stated-in-google-getting-started-page-and/29505604#29505604)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `double`. `long` it's for integer numbers. In your JSON numbers with a floating point.

Comment: I used double in my PositionResponse class but anyway the result was the same as before. I mean nothing. Do you have any another ideas?