# Google Map API Error?

Tags: android, google-maps

I got this Logcat message printed below.

```
10-09 15:57:14.306: I/dalvikvm(7755): Could not find method android.content.pm.PackageManager.getPackageInstaller, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zzg
```

My map is not loading because of this. Here I got similar question but not find any solution yet.

[Unfortunately, (App Name) has stopped when i use fragment to use Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29567747/unfortunately-app-name-has-stopped-when-i-use-fragment-to-use-google-maps)

I am doing few operation with google map v2 in my activity. Does anybody have possible solution?

Complete Logcat output:

> 10-09 18:35:16.418: I/dalvikvm(31472): Could not find method android.content.pm.PackageManager.getPackageInstaller, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zzg
>   10-09 18:35:16.418: W/dalvikvm(31472): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 513: Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;.getPackageInstaller ()Landroid/content/pm/PackageInstaller;
>   10-09 18:35:16.418: D/dalvikvm(31472): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000b
>   10-09 18:35:16.518: I/dalvikvm(31472): Could not compile trace for Ljava/util/Arrays;fill, offset 7
>   10-09 18:35:16.518: I/dalvikvm(31472): 
>   10-09 18:35:16.518: I/dalvikvm(31472): JIT_INFO: ME Issues while compiling trace  Ljava/util/Arrays;fill, offset 7
>   10-09 18:35:16.518: I/dalvikvm(31472):  The trace provoked a spill.
>   10-09 18:35:16.518: I/dalvikvm(31472): Trying less registerization from 1 to 0
>   10-09 18:35:16.528: I/dalvikvm(31472): Could not compile trace for Ljava/util/Arrays;fill, offset 5
>   10-09 18:35:16.528: I/dalvikvm(31472): 
>   10-09 18:35:16.528: I/dalvikvm(31472): JIT_INFO: ME Issues while compiling trace  Ljava/util/Arrays;fill, offset 5
>   10-09 18:35:16.528: I/dalvikvm(31472):  The trace provoked a spill.
>   10-09 18:35:16.528: I/dalvikvm(31472): Trying less registerization from 1 to 0

Comment: Please update your play service lib and then try.

Comment: I have updated Google play services as suggested in answer of linked question. But still, there is same problem.

Comment: Do u use eclipse or android studio? do u try both emulator or real device?

Comment: Eclipse. I tried with real device.

Comment: My suggestion is to move to `Android Studio` for android development, but [here](set up google play services sdk) is how to set correct version of `play service` for `Eclipse`.